# Instagram API dynamically login

Tags: php, api, authentication, instagram

I have 2 pages to allow user to fetch images from instagram index.php and home.php

In index.php, provided login button to allow user to login.

```
<?php
$loginUrl = $instagram->getLoginUrl();
echo "<a class='button' href='$loginUrl'>Sign in with Instagram</a>";
?>
```

In home.php, it gets the code from the return url from index.php and get the images.

My problem is, I dont want to direct user to login, I wish only 1 php page to save my login id and password inside and dynamically login and save my image to db by using only 1 page which means that to combine index.php and home.php without using any button.

How should I do this? I am new to php and stuck in this.
Please help and I am really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: You want to save your user's Instagram password ? Um... Safe ?

Comment: Actually I develop this program for my own. That's why I want to save my own id and password into the code. I dont wan to login everytime I run the page. =)

Comment: Did you read this : http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/ ?

Comment: ya but i dont understand @ShivanRaptor

Comment: Then try to understand & implement.